# Limits in category of cones.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm trying to do exercise 2.17.2 in Borceux's "Handbook of Categorical Algebra":

Consider a functor $F: \mathfrak{D} \to \mathfrak{C}$ and the category of cones on $F$. Show that $F$ has a limit if and only if the functor $U$ from the category of cones on $F$ to $\mathfrak{C}$ mapping a cone to its vertex has a colimit.

Here is what I thought, however I'm not sure if I should take a different approach or just fill the gaps in the proof.  I hope you can help me:

$\Rightarrow$ If $F$ has a limit $L$ we know that  limit is a terminal object in the category of cones on $F$ .So the inclusion functor is a final functor. And we get the result.

$\Leftarrow$ Now suppose $U$ has a colimit $L$, now we fix some $D \in \mathfrak{D}$ and there exists morphisms from each cone vertex to $FD$.
This makes $FD$ the vertex of a cocone $\implies \exists ! ~ \alpha_D: L \to FD$.

So $(L, \alpha_D)$ is a cone such that for every other cone $C_i, ~ \exists ~ h_i: C_i \to L$.  How do I prove uniqueness of the factorization?

PS: I edited the first implication because I found a proposition that helped me. So i just need to finish the last one.

Comment: I'm confused. $L$ is the image of the limit cone by $U$, but if you are able to find a cone $L'\Rightarrow F(-)$ (which is the most natural thing to expect) then you get an arrow $L'\to L$.

Comment: I think i have the arrows needed but i don't know how to prove uniqueness of the factorizations. I can edit the part you find confusing if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conceptual key is that a terminal object in a category is the same thing as a colimit for the whole category (i.e. a colimit for the identity functor on the category as a diagram in that category).

To see this note the mere existence of a co-cone from a whole category to one of its objects $T$ shows $T$ is weakly terminal and the co-cone component $c_T:T\rightarrow T$ coequalizes any pair of arrows $f,g:A\rightarrow T$ in the category.  But then $c_T$ induces a co-cone map from the  co-cone to itself, so the colimit property says it is the identity on $T$.  So there cannot be distinct arrows $f\neq g:A\rightarrow T$ in the category.

As you say, a limit for $F$ is a terminal object in the category of cones on $F$.  So it is a colimit for the identity diagram in that category.  So you need to show a colimit for the identity diagram in the cone category amounts to the same thing as a colimit to the diagram of vertices of those cones in $\mathfrak{C}$.  That follows quickly from the reasoning you have done, showing a colimit $L$ for the diagram of vertices is the vertex of a cone $(L, \alpha_D)$ over $F$.

Comment: Thank you. I think i got it but let me show what i thought.

Using my reasoning i've found that L is an object in the category of cones satisfying for every A in the cone category exists an arrow from that object to L. So it's seems like L  is the limit of the identity functor.

Now suppose another cone L' in the category of cones, since L is the limit of U there exists a unique arrow from L to L' in $ \mathfrak{C}$.

L must be terminal in the category of cones iff L is the limit of F

Comment: @Abellan You have a good insight but slightly wrong.  The property you describe is close to saying $L$ is a limit of the empty diagram in the cone category, not of the identity diagram.  In fact a limit to the empty diagram is a *co*-limit to the identity diagram as shown above.  Compare the idea that the supremum of a lattice is the greatest lower bound to the empty subset of the lattice, and the least upper bound to the whole lattice.

Comment: sorry i meant colimit of the identity functor in my comment.

Is it correct now? I supposed another cone and because U has a colimit i found an unique factorization.

Thanks for your time. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Abellan Yes that seems right.  Like a lot of things in category theory the key is to get the grammar/terminology just right, and then the reasoning is simple.